# Index Tracking Problem

Tags: portfolio-optimization, index, mean-variance, factor-loading

I have set up a mean variance optimization problem,

$$min:{W}^{\prime}{\Sigma_{\varepsilon}{W}}$$
$$s.t:{W}^{\prime}{\alpha}=R_B\;,\;\;W^{\prime}l={1},\;\;W'\beta=0,\;\;W'Z=\beta_p$$

where, $W$ is an ($n+1$)vector and the last value ($W_{n+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i\beta_i$ ),

$\;\Sigma_{\varepsilon}$ is the covariance matrix of residuals as proposed by the diagonal model,

$\alpha$ is an $(n+1)$ vector of estimated alpha values expect for the last value which is the benchmark return $R_B$,

$l$ is an ($n+1$) vector of ones expect for the last value which is $0$,

$\beta$ is an ($n+1$) vector of ones expect for the last value which is $-1$

$W'Z=\beta_p$ is a condition that the beta of my portfolio is a value that I desire, so $Z$ is a vector of $0$s expect for the last value which is 1.

I am trying to form a portfolio that replicates the market index, as you can see I have not set up this problem in the tracking error framework ( I just started reading it). I have kept the condition $W'\beta=0$ because this is the way the diagonal model was initially set up by the book I have been reading.

Can this model work to replicate a market index if I set up my exposure $\beta_p=1$? could it help me tilt my exposure say if I wanted a portfolio beta of 1.5 ?. Thanks for your help !!

Comment: if you want to track an index, then the QP formulation has to be written with respect to that index. So, in your objective function, the weights are written as differences between the weights in the portfolio and the weights in the index.  It would also be useful to  have an equity model that provides the exposures that each stock in the index has to the different factors. I can't explain this in detail here. I'll look  on the net  to see if I can find something.. It's been a long time so I'm not up to speed on the literature but the  concept could not have changed very much over the years.

Comment: Note that, in my comment above, I didn't mean to imply that you have to use an equity model. But you definitely should be including the weights of the stocks in the index so that you can write the variance as a variance of ( the difference of the  return to portfolio and return to index ). If you are interested in incorporating an equity model, then this link points to a document that explains three different approaches. The last one by Grinold and Kahn is pretty much what Barra does. https://www.cfainstitute.org/-/media/documents/book/rf-publication/1994/rf-v1994-n4-4445-pdf.ashx